# Split strings in R column and get max of split string

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that has a column with numbers contained within a string

e.g.

```
test<-data.frame(a=c('"1;2;3;4"','".;.;."',NA,'"5;.;7;8"'))
```

I would like to create a second column that is either the max of the split string or NA if this is not available.

I have tried:

```
test$b<- ifelse(!is.na(test$a),as.numeric(max(strsplit(test$a, ";"))),NA)
```

but it throws an error.

so test$b should equal 4,NA,NA,8

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here  is an option where we split the 'a' column by characters that are not digits,  then loop over the `list` with a condition `if` `all` values are NA return `NA` or else  get the `max` of `numeric` values

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(test$a), '[;"]'), function(x) 
   if(all(is.na(as.numeric(x)))) NA else max(as.numeric(x), na.rm = TRUE))
#[1]  4 NA NA  8
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this does work absolutely perfectly on the example I provided. However in my actual data there decimal places which seem to cause some confusion for it. So for example : test<-data.frame(a=c('"0.1;0.2;0.3;0.4"','".;.;."',NA,'"0.5;.;0.7;0.8"')). Sorry for the change!

Answer (score 2):

`[[:punct:]]`  will filter out `! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _` { | } ~.`

For more info, read this: `?regex`

```
test$b <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(test$a, "[[:punct:]]"), function(x) {
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, max(x, na.rm = TRUE))
} ))
test
#           a  b
# 1 "1;2;3;4"  4
# 2   ".;.;." NA
# 3      <NA> NA
# 4 "5;.;7;8"  8
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R solution might be using `regmatches` + `sapply`, e.g.,

```
test <- within(test,b <- sapply(regmatches(a,gregexpr("\\d+",a)),
                                function(x) ifelse(length(x),max(as.numeric(x)),NA)))
```

such that

```
> test
          a  b
1 "1;2;3;4"  4
2   ".;.;." NA
3      <NA> NA
4 "5;.;7;8"  8
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I've gone with the answer from akrun but this seems to work perfectly too.

Comment: @mgene No worries! akrun's answer used `strsplit`, which is more close to your attempt :)

Answer (score 1):

Using data.table package:

```
# set up:
library(data.table)
setDT(test)

# solution:
test[, b := as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(gsub('"', "", a), ";"), max)), by = 1:4]
```